# Rails - f.select and only some values from the given hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, select, hash

I am using this code for displaying data to the `f.select` tag:

```
  <%= f.select :status, STATUSES, {}, :class => 'form-control' %>
```

The `STATUSES` hash contains following:

```
STATUSES = {"A" => 0,
            "B" => 1,
            "C" => 2,
            "D" => 3,
            "E" => 4}
```

How to display from the hash only values smaller than than 4 (so "A", "B", "C" and "D")?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this:

```
STATUSES.reject { |key, value| value >= 4 }
```

If so, I would personally create a helper method for it (not sure if you've got access to the `STATUSES` constant here though):

```
module StatusHelper
  def statuses_collection
    STATUSES.reject { |key, value| value >= 4 }
  end
end
```

And in your view:

```
<%= f.select :status, statuses_collection, {}, :class => 'form-control' %>
```

Comment: or the other way `STATUSES.select { |key, value| value <=3  }`   :)

Comment: `STATUSES.select { |key, value| value < 4 }` looks better

Answer (score 0):

I'd reccomend you setup your hash in the controller if that's possible.

However, if you want to do all the business in the select form code you could try something like this:

```
      <%= f.select(:status, options_for_select(STATUSES.map { |key, value| [key, value] if value < 4 }), {}, class: 'form-control') %>
```

Not perfect but that works in Rails 3.

Answer (score 0):

Without any broader context, I would recommend filtering it in the controller.

`def your_controller_method
  @statuses = STATUSES.reject{ |k,v| v >= 4 }
end`

then in your view:

`<%= f.select :status, @statuses, {}, :class => 'form-control' %>`

Answer (score 0):

Same as 'reject' above but the conditional looks better

```
STATUSES.select {|key,value| value < 4}
```